# How to setup to use background callbacks in dash app

Tags: docker, docker-compose, plotly-dash

I have a dash application. I have use docker-compose, services as below:

- **web:** # my custom dash app image. I have used gunicorn to start it in docker file
- **proxy:** # built-in nginx image
- **db:** # built-in postgres image
- **pgadmin:** # built-in pgadmin image

This above setup is running fine.

Now, I have **added functionality where user can upload csv files**. For this I am trying to use **background callback**.
I have read the documentation on dash website for the same but confuse how to setup this.

What I understand is as below:
I will need following

- **redis:** # built-in redis image
- install (under web), pip install **dash[celery]**
- write a code from dash website as demo/test code

Issuses are as follow:

- do I need to install (under web) pip install -U **"celery[redis]"**
- how to **start/initialize celery_app** i.e. celery -A app:celery_app worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=2

  - as in web service, I am starting gunicorn, how start celery also from same docker file
- or do I need new service as say

  - eg **worker:** # my custom dash app image (same as web) and start/initiate celery_app in docker file

    - by doing so am I duplicating the same web code twice, one service(web) to start gunicorn and other service (worker) to start celery_app

Please suggest.

**Updated**

**project structure:**

- main.py
- proj

  - manage.py
  - visuals

    - app.py  # This is dash application

**Installed:**

- dash[celery]

**app.py:**

```
REDIS_URL='redis://localhost:6379/0'

celery_app = Celery(__name__, broker=REDIS_URL, backend=REDIS_URL)
background_callback_manager = CeleryManager(celery_app=celery_app)


app = Dash(
    __name__,
    background_callback_manager=background_callback_manager,
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
    suppress_callback_exceptions=True,
)

server = app.server
```

**docker-compose:**

```
  web:
    container_name: web_application
    build: .
    command: ["gunicorn", "--workers", "2", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--preload", "main:create_app()"]
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
    env_file:
    depends_on:
      - db
      - pgadmin
      - celery
    volumes:      

  
  celery:
    container_name: celery_application
    build: .
    # command: "celery -A main:create_celery_app() worker --loglevel=INFO"
    command: "celery -A main:celery_app worker --loglevel=INFO"
    restart: always
    networks:
    env_file:
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
```

**Errors:**

```
 Error: Invalid value for '-A' / '--app': 
celery_application | Unable to load celery application.
celery_application | While trying to load the module main the following error occurred:
celery_application | Traceback (most recent call last):
celery_application |   File ".venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 1250, in backend
celery_application |     return self._local.backend
celery_application |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
celery_application | AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'backend'

celery_application | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "'redis"
```

Comment: [Multiple Docker containers and Celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863053/multiple-docker-containers-and-celery) includes a reasonable walkthrough (I'd consider it fine to use the same image for both parts, the answer there advocates a separate worker image); [Celery and Flask in same docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098668/celery-and-flask-in-same-docker-compose) begins with a typical Compose setup (ignore the now-obsolete `links:`).  Do either of those setups help you?

Comment: Hi David, Thanks. I will try to create a demo prototype using given links. My first way will be to create two services(web and worker) that will have or using same base image but both will have different commands(gunicorn and celery). My second way to use single image with both commands(I am googling how to start both commands but not sure how to do it without supervisord)

Comment: A container is a wrapper around a single process, but you can run multiple containers off of the same image with different commands.  In a Compose context you'd provide an alternate `command:` for the Celery worker.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks. I implemented the changes using the first way as you suggested but getting error

Comment: Hi David, I did installed the dependencies as dash[celery], This installs both celery[redis] and redis. Also, I tried adding redis explicitly but still getting the same errors

Comment: Hi David, Finally some progress. I replaced localhost to service name of celery [REDIS_URL=redis://celery:6379/0]. But still it does not working. Getting error as 
celery_application | [2022-12-24 15:53:47,437: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://celery:6379/0: Error 111 connecting to celery:6379. Connection refused..
celery_application | Trying again in 6.00 seconds... (3/100)

Comment: Something on port 6379 I'd usually expect to be a Redis server, not your Celery worker.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks. Finally it worked. I found your this post, explaining my initial problem to choose one of the approach, in more simple way Refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57337338/how-to-run-flask-and-celery-in-one-container), I have used the same approach from this.

Comment: I also checked [docker image ls] and observed that there are 2 images one for web and other for celery. I thought there will be 1 image as it common for both, just commands are different while launching the container. since size of my web image is approx 970 MB. This makes (970 + 970). Can you suggest something on this? or is it ok to have like this. what is the general preferred way for this.

Comment: If the two images have the same hash in the `docker image ls` listing, they are literally the same image and do not use any extra space.  This is normal with this setup.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks. You mean Image ID? If yes, Then yes both web image and celery image have same ID. Also forgot to mention, I replaced celery service name with redis service name in REDIS_URL.